# Return list of all values that match Two criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I am trying to setup a formula that returns values that satisfy two criteria. 
E.g.

```
  A       B         C
1 Bob     Banana    10   
2 John    Banana    10
3 Steven  Apple     5
4 Elliott Apple     2
5 Andrew  Apple     5
```

I want to return a list of names with the values in column B and C that equal Apple and 5, respectively.

I have used a variant of the formula below to successfully return one value but am having trouble getting the second value into this formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$4,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$4=$D$1,ROW($B$1:$B$4)-ROW($B$1)+1),ROWS($B$1:$B1))),"")
```

if someone could help me work that is out that would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Have you ruled out just filtering on those two columns?  Is D1 where you specify the B value, and the idea would be to specify the C value in another cell?  What do you want returned (row numbers, only A values since B & C are specified, all three values)?  What form do you need the output in (consolidated list, replicated values or indicator in each qualifying row, highlighting qualifying values)?  Is every name unique or can there be duplicates?  If the names are unique or you want a list of unique qualifying values, depending on the output requirements a pivot table could work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This Array formula can solve the issue:**

[image]

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($J$38:$L$42, SMALL(IF(COUNTIFS($J$44, $K$38:$K$42, $K$44, $L$38:$L$42), ROW($J$38:$L$42)-MIN(ROW($J$38:$L$42))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),"")}
```

**N.B.**

- Finish formula in Cell `J46`, with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**, fill Right then Down.
- Cell `J44` & `K44` comprises criteria

---

- Your Formula search values only in one Column,,
  `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$4`
- Also it matches only one criteria instead of two,

`IF($B$1:$B$4=$D$1`

---

*Now, let me describe the mechanism behind the Array formula:*

```
 =INDEX($J$38:$L$42, SMALL({False, False, 3, False, 5}, ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1))
```

becomes,

`=INDEX($J$38:$L$42, 3, 5)`

Returns Names then by dragging Right & Down the others values.

```
(IF(COUNTIFS($J$44, $K$38:$K$42, $K$44, $L$38:$L$42), ROW($J$38:$L$42)-MIN(ROW($J$38:$L$42))+1)
```

Returns,

`IF({0, 0, 1, 0, 1,}, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

And finally the combination of TRUE/FALSE & row number `3` & `5` like this,

`{False,False, 3, False, 5}` get combined with `INDEX` & `SMALL`, shown above also.

- Formula is wrapped with `IFERROR` to replace error with blanks, if formula doesn't finds the value.

*Adjust cell references in Formula as needed.*

Comment: You can wrap a formula in `AGGREGATE` without the `IF` statement to avoid the array entering, otherwise, good explaination.

Comment: @JvdV,, thanks for the feedback,, yes `AGGREGATE` can fix it also but this method is comparatively easier !!

Comment: @fixer1234,, yeah I found typo while reading ,,☺

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. How would I go about it when I want to output the matches on a separate sheet?

Comment: disregard my last question. I worked it out. Cheers.

Comment: Glad to help you @Shaun,, keep asking !!

Answer (score 3):

Rajesh S ran with the approach you attempted and demonstrated how to make that work.  If the data is dynamic, that has you covered.  But if you only need to periodically extract a results table, I'll toss in a couple of really simple alternatives.  These can be done in minutes, even if you're out of coffee for your brain.

**Filtering**

In the image below, I deselected the filters after copying the results so you could see the source data.

[image]

- Highlight the data you want to use for criteria.
- Turn on filtering.
- Select the values you want in the filters.  This will hide everything you don't want.
- Select what's displayed, copy it, paste it to your results area.

Need different criteria?  Select the new criteria.  Copy and paste.

**Pivot Table**

For a given set of criteria, every qualifying record will have a name and then repeat the criteria on each record.  If you are generating reports for different criteria, you will want to keep the criteria with the result.  But if you don't need it on every record, a pivot table offers a fast way to do it.

[image]

- Highlight the data.
- From the toolbar or menu, Insert Pivot Table.
- Drag the Name field to the Rows window.  Drag the Fruit and Number fields to the filters.
- Select your criteria in the filters.

The result is the list of qualifying names, with the criteria summarized in the heading.

You can copy the pivot table and have two pasting choices.  A normal paste will give you another pivot table.  You can change the filter criteria in it for another case.  Paste Special, Values will paste a copy of the results.

Comment: Really both are good solution, if one don't like using Function/Formula ☺